Why is φ ⊨ ∀x.φwhen p(x) ⇒ ∀x.p(x) is contingent, not valid?
http://intrologic.stanford.edu/exercises/exercise_08_01.html
In the link above in question 4, it says p(x) ⇒ ∀x.p(x)
http://intrologic.stanford.edu/exercises/exercise_08_02.html
However, in the next exercise it also says φ ⊨ ∀x.φ is true.
I don't really get it. Aren't those two the same thing? Why is one valid when another is contingent? Is it because of the difference between implication and entailment?

Does it help you if you rewrite it as $p(x) \implies \forall y.p(y)$?

For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., basic help on mathjax notation, mathjax tutorial and quick reference, main meta site math tutorial and equation editing how-to.

The difference is that "$⇒$" is part of the logical language used to form sentences, whereas "$⊨$" is a symbol in the language we use to talk about sentences, so in the first question you have a single sentence "$p(x)⇒∀x.p(x)$", whereas in the second question you have separate sentences "$φ$" and "$∀x.φ$". This matters because free variables are implicitly $∀$-quantified at the sentence level, so the first one is like $∀x.(p(x)⇒∀y.p(y))$ and the second one is like $(∀x.p(x))⊨(∀x.p(x))$.
